# how to set parameter in setBackgroundColor function

Tags: android, colors, hex, alpha

I want to change alpha value of background dynamically using an seekbar.
I used this:

```
Mylayout.setBackgroundColor(int Mycolor);
```

MyColor is Black (0x000000) but alpha is 0-255.

my code is like this:

```
Mycolor = User_alpha * 256*256*256; // to build : 0xAA000000
//User_alpha range : 1-254
```

if User_alpha = 250 then User_alpha * 256*256* can not fit in integer range and overflow will occur!

how can I set MyColor using User_alpha ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Color has the static method argb. You can specify the 4 components (a, r, g, b) as int. It returns back the int you are looking for. E.g

```
 int color = Color.arbg(255, 255, 255, 255);
```

You can find the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#argb(int,%20int,%20int,%20int))

by the way, every component is represent by 1 byte, meaning that it can holds values between 0 and 255

Comment: TanQ bro, you helped me so much.